# JAVA_HOME not visiable in system variables

Tags: java, java-8, java-home

After downloading and instaling `Java 8 JDK` on `Windows 10` i wanted to make sure that `JAVA_HOME` system variable is set correctly, however in Enviroment variables `JAVA_HOME` is not defined.
 Do i have to create such variable manually and set it to desired path or did something went wrong during instalation?
 any tips?

Comment: ye you will have to create it

Comment: Is 'java --version ' is working if you run it from java installation directory?  If yes,  no problem with installion and you need to set JAVA_HOME manually.

Comment: yes, it is working, i have created this variable manually and set, but just wondering why it was not created during instalation